# Django 1.10 Need help using CreateView to add data in model which has relationship with other models(e.g. Classroom->School->User)

Tags: python, django, django-models

My django version is 1.11 and new to Django using CreateView for multiple tables.
I have been trying to link the 3 models i.e. User(django built-in), School and Classroom. I need to create a new classroom which has relationship with the School and User model so how can add them to the Classroom model when creating a new class.

I have the following simplied version of the code,

In urls.py of app named basic_app,

```
url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
url(r'^class/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.ClassroomView,name='classroom_list'),
url(r'^class/create/(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.ClassroomCreateView.as_view(),name='createClassroom'),
```

In models.py,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse 

class School(models.Model):
 #1-1 relationship with django built-in User model
 user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
 principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
 location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.name

 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("basic_app:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Classroom(models.Model):
 school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 class_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
 desc = models.CharField(max_length=256)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.class_name
```

When the user click on the following link after login,

```
<a href="{% url 'basic_app:createClassroom' pk=user.pk %}">Create Classroom
```

In views.py,

```
def user_login(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    # First get the username and password supplied
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    # Django's built-in authentication function:
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        #Check it the account is active
        if user.is_active:
            # Log the user in.
            login(request,user)

            return redirect(reverse('basic_app:classroom_list', kwargs={'pk': user.id}))

#login redirects to ClassroomView 
def ClassroomView(request,pk):


 classroom_list = Classroom.objects\
                    .filter(school__user=User.objects.get(pk=pk))\

 class_dict = {'class_records': classroom_list}
 return render(request, 'basic_app/classroom_list.html', context=class_dict)

#when clicked on create class on template

class ClassroomCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):

login_url = '/login/'
redirect_field_name = 'basic_app/classroom_list.html'

template_name = 'basic_app/form.html'

fields = ('class_name', 'desc')
model = Classroom


 def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user
    self.object.school = School.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])#how to get school since it is linked by User and I have user id from login
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

I can login in users, take them to list of classes. When I click on the create class link it will take them to the form asking for Class name and Desc but when I press the submit button it shows the error:

```
DoesNotExist at /basic_app/class/create/3
School matching query does not exist.
```

The error originates at ClassroomCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView)

```
 self.object.school = School.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

How can I link School to Classroom model? Since I have Classroom linked to School and School linked to User, how can I get school id since I already have User id from login. I would really appreciate any insights and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

you can get school for logged user

```
try:
    user_school = School.objects.get(user=request.user)
except School.DoesNotExist:
    # user has no school 
    pass
```